# How to change referenda voting period in openGov?

Tags: opengov, referendum, pokadot

i am using polkadot(1.1.0) version . i am trying to use referendum in it  when i submit proposal it is showing  time(voting period) . how to changes that voting period value  in it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adjust this value.

The time for making a decision is referred to as the voting period.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/18d53dbf91e90c48d535c3e1f59a3383b569bdb3/substrate/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L939C5-L939C5